# N-Tier Application Design

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am fairly new to Arhitecture Designs in OOP ( I'm coming from programming robotics, so it's a bit of a struggle ). The team that I am taking part of is creating a rather large application and the Leading Project Manager presented us with the requirements and in that requirements we must use Layers in creating the modules. The technologies we are using are C# WinForms and Oracle for the data-store.

My module consists of User Administration and I have tried to separate the logic from the implementation, so I have the following arhitecture:

- Business Layer
- Data Layer
- Presentation Layer

I am using the Repository Pattern and IoC with EF and everything looks and works fine but now my boss has told me that I need to seperate the Presentation Layer from the Data Layer completely. The problem consists that from the Presentation Layer I use IoC and if I want to create a User object for example I do the following:

```
_userRepo.InsertNewUser(new User { props here } ); .
```

So this is incorrect because I access the DAL directly. My boss has told me that I need another layer that isolates these kind of calls and implement Business Rules ( ?! )

I have searched and researched the internet and I found nothing of help ( mainly because everything is filtered here at work ).

I think my boss wants something of a Domain Layer / Service Layer but I have no ideea how to implement it in the current design. I can post the project without any problem, any sensitive data will be removed from the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The reasons why you would attempt to do that is that you have two or more different PLs or your backend APIs are used by other applications. For example you have web, desktop and mobile application that is going to use the same backend APIs. Is this the case? If not, your boss is overcomplicateing things, remember YAGNI.

Comment: @oleksii even though I agree with YAGNI, speration of concerns is also important. For example if you want to change from EF to some other ORM framework, you will have to touch the BL, which you shouldn't...

Comment: @derape if I want to change from EF to something else, I'd do it before I select an ORM. Building abstraction over abstract ORM is a waste and over-complication. Such abstraction also removes specific details about ORM, which are in my opinion rather useful.

Comment: @oleksii I don't think there is a "golden rule" on that topic, it really depends on your application design and requirements, etc. So I don't we can give a detailed "good" answer here...

Comment: I would check how other colleagues are doing it...

Comment: @ Unfortunately only one of my colleagues are working on the project, and he said f*** Arhitecture Design, I won't argue with him. So I don't have anyone to ask, yet :-). @oleksii - My boss is a old man, he has lots of experience but he is so old-school I can't even try talking him out of this :-)

Comment: If you are using EF to generate say poco objects, or even use code first, then these poco objects are not really part of the DAL, they are part of the domain layer. I put these in a seperate project, the repository for instance is part of the DAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer, even though it might be opinion-based, and even though I cannot read your boss's mind :-)

Fundamentally, I think what your boss wants is to **reduce dependencies** between all layers. The architectural pattern you choose to do this, depends on the application at hand. What you described looks like a [three-tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture). Let us briefly recall how a three-tier architecture looks like, and how things are supposed to work:

- The presentation tier displays information and serves as a boundary to the user.
- The application tier (or business logic) controls the functionality of the application. In particular it processes data and distributes it to the other tiers.
- The data tier, containing the data access layer (DAL), stores or retrieves data. It should keep your application independent from the storage solution at hand. It will usually work with data access objects (DAOs).

There are different schools of thought when it comes to which tier should know which other tiers. But from what I read, I think you are supposed to promote the business logic as kind of mediator. This means, the business logic knows the presentation tier and the data tier, but the other tiers do not know each other. I try to clarify this by going through two sample scenarios:

**A. Display an existing user**

1. Business logic asks data tier for a specific `User` DAO, e.g. the one corresponding to `id==123`.
2. Data tier returns the `User` object.
3. Business logic reads the values stored in the `User` object and sets the values in the presentation tier accordingly, e.g. the `firstName`, `lastName` etc. It does **not** forward the `User` itself, only the contained values.

**B. Create a new user**

1. Presentation tier collects all values necessary to create the new user.
2. When "submitting", these values arrive in the business logic (e.g. IoC).
3. The business logic tells the data tier to create a new `User` object with the values it got from the presentation tier.
4. The data tier creates and stores the object.

What creates **dependencies** between the different tiers are the DAOs. I.e. if your presentation tier was to instantiate a `User` object, it would need to import a class belonging to the DAL (which is not what your boss wants).
So what you can do instead is to leave all the communication between presentation tier and data tier to the business logic.

As an alternative in scenario B, you can also make the business logic create the `User`, so that your DAL methods get simpler.

As I said in the beginning, there is no one way of doing it. If you need more specific information or have further questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the all the answers and guidelines so far.

I think what my boss wants ( I didn't get reach of him because he is in DE and I am in RO ) is to fully separate the concerns between layers, something like the Model-View-Presentation Pattern, so that the Presentation Layer ( UI ) will not directly access the Data Layer. It can access it but through an intermediary layer.

I added a Domain/Service Layer to the application and now the Presentation Layer calls the Service Layer and the Service Layer calls the Business Layer and creates the user / group objects.

The following thing is, he said something about Business Rules that this Domain Layer should include. What are these Business Rules, an example would be appreciated?

The only think I came up for Business Rules were some Validation Rules, suchs as: Before you call: return userRepository.GetUserName( User user ) check the User object passed as a parameter that is not null, or similar checks.

So now the "mechanics" are:

In the Presentation Layer I inject into the constructor the IService object and then I use the IService object to call a method for example "GetAllUsers()".

The IService per-se is in fact a "copy" of the User Object's Repository class so when the IService object calls "GetAllUsers()", there is a exact named method in the IService classes that will do: "return _userRepository.GetAllUsers()" - in this way the Presentation Layer calls object specific methods through an Intermediary Layer and this Intermediary Layer will have direct access to certain methods of the DL.

I hope I made my self as clearly as possible. I will provide screenshots if necessary.

As I stated before, I'm just beggining to have experience with Arhitecture Design, since in the robotic fields there is no such thing, so please do not throw so many rocks :D